# How to refresh activity after creating dynamic controls in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gallery

In my activity Oncreate() function im calling an **AsyncTask**. In that **PostExecute(**) im creating some **dynamic gallery controls** and calling **ImageAdapterL.notifyDataSetChanged();**. but Im getting Null Pointer exception.

I need to refresh the activity without calling Oncreate()[B'coz in Oncreate only im calling async Task].

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        new testAynscTask().execute();
    }
    private class testAynscTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            processTogetImages();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        CreateDynamicGallery();
            aImageAdapterL.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
public void CreateDynamicGallery(){
        CategoryGalleryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        Gallery g = new Gallery(getApplicationContext());
        GalleryLayout.addView(g,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            g.setSpacing(15);


        aImageAdapterL = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        g.setAdapter(aImageAdapterL);
        g[positionP].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code, maybe?

Comment: @Rajesh check my updated question with code

Comment: Where do you create `aImageAdapterL`? Post your logcat output too.

Comment: code is fine. but what is there in CreateDynamicGallery()?

Comment: @bhuro CreateDynamicGallery function added

Comment: getApplicationContext() => this

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you aren't really refreshing the activity, just the images in the adapter. I'd suggest calling createDynamicGallery from onCreate with a null adapter (a well written adapter view should handle a null adapter by treating it as empty) then load your images and populate the real adapter (or a new adapter) with the images. Setting the gallery view's adapter to the real adapter should cause the gallery to refresh and all will be well.

As an additional observation you might want to look at using an asynctaskloader with a loadermanager to help you deal with rotation correctly. With your current code, if the async task takes a long time to execute it might be possible to get errors (likely "activity destroyed" errors) or a race condition with two async tasks trying to load images after a screen rotation.